# how to hide next sibling in java script with class

Tags: javascript

I need to hide "description box" (red border box) on the click
of "hide this" button. I have select all button by using loop and also added on click function by using "add event listener". But am unable to hide it's sibling. how to achieve this?

```js
var hideBtn, i;
hideBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-this');

for (i = 0; i < hideBtn.length; i++) {
  hideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello');
  })
}
```

```css
.hide-this {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.description {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were good, just have to use `nextElementSibling` to change display to 'none'

```js
var hideBtn, i;
    hideBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-this');
    
  for(i=0; i<hideBtn.length; i++){
        hideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
             if(this.nextElementSibling.style.display == 'none')
               this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
          else
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
        })
    }
```

```css
.hide-this{
        background:red;
        padding:10px;
        width:100px;
        display: block;
        width:100px;
    }

    .description{
        border:1px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        width:100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
 <a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description" >
  This is our description
</div>


  
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>


    
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`Element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) and [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to ensure that you are targeting the element `.hide-this` that is placed immediately after the clicked button.

To get *which* button that is actually clicked is a matter of accessing `e.currentTarget` of the click event:

```js
const hideBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-this');

hideBtns.forEach(hideBtn => {
  hideBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const description = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    if (description && description.matches('.description')) {
      description.classList.toggle('hide-this');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-this {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.description {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>



<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>



<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.nextElementSibling` to get the slibling element

```js
var hideBtn, i;
    hideBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-this');
    
   
    for(i=0; i<hideBtn.length; i++){
        hideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
           alert('Hello');
           let next = this.nextElementSibling
           next.style.display = 'none';
  
        })
    }
```

```css
.hide-this{
        background:red;
        padding:10px;
        width:100px;
        display: block;
        width:100px;
    }

    .description{
        border:1px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        width:100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
    <div class="description" >
        This is our description
    </div>


  
    <a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
    <div class="description">
        This is our description
    </div>


    
    <a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
    <div class="description">
        This is our description
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var hideBtn, i;
hideBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-this');

for (i = 0; i < hideBtn.length; i++) {
  hideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("none")
  })
}
```

```css
.hide-this {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.description {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.none {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
<a class="hide-this">Hide This</a>
<div class="description">
  This is our description
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using event delegation, rather than binding-up numerous event listeners which all perform the same function:

```js
document.body.addEventListener( "click", { target } => {
    if ( target.classList.contains( "hide-this" ) && target.nextElementSibling ) {
        target.nextElementSibling.hidden = true;
    }
});
```

You wouldn't need to put the listener on the `body` either; a more appropriate place would be the first common container for all of the *hide-this* elements, and their description siblings:

```html
<body>
    <section id="descItems">
        <input type="button" class="hide-this">Hide This</input>
        <div class="description">...</div>
        <input type="button" class="hide-this">Hide This</input>
        <div class="description">...</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

```js
descItems.addEventListener( "click", { target } => {
    if ( target.classList.contains( "hide-this" ) && target.nextElementSibling ) {
        target.nextElementSibling.hidden = true;
    }
});
```